# In javacc How to do multi choice token with token assignment

Tags: java, compiler-construction, javacc

Code first:

```
// I need, but not allowed
o = (<I_EXIT> | <I_RET> | <I_NOP>)

// Work around, the generated code will do double switch
(o = <I_EXIT> | o = <I_RET> | o = <I_NOP>)

// Work around, introduce new token, will warning
// Warning: Line 59, Column 11: Regular Expression choice : XXX can never be matched as : XXX
// Consider this is a bad practice.
TOKEN:{
    <I_NO_OP: <I_EXIT> | <I_RET> | <I_NOP>>
}
o = <I_NO_OP>

// Work around, introduce new grammar, generate double switch with one more function call, looks awful.
Token oneOp():{
    Token t = null;
}{
    (t = <I_CALL> |t = <I_PUSH> |t = <I_POP> |t = <I_JPC>){return t;}
}
...
o = oneOp() a = operand()
```

I [picked](https://github.com/wenerme/bbvm/blob/java/bbvm-core/src/main/jjtree/me/wener/bbvm/asm/BBAsmParser.jjt#L95)

```
(o = <I_EXIT> | o = <I_RET> | o = <I_NOP>)
```

It's looks better. Is there any other way to do this ? I'm not sure is this the right way to do this..

The whole jjt is [here](https://github.com/wenerme/bbvm/blob/java/bbvm-core/src/main/jjtree/me/wener/bbvm/asm/BBAsmParser.jjt)

Comment: Is there a particular reason why the first option is not allowed?

Comment: Compile error `org.javacc.jjtree.ParseException: Encountered " "(" "( "  "<" "< "" ` JavaCC 6.1.2

Comment: @Acapulco Here `o` is a Token variable and `(<I_EXIT> | <I_RET> | <I_NOP>)` is syntactic regular expression. It happens that this particular regular expression only matches token sequences of length 1.  However, in general, a regular expression could match a sequence of tokens of any length.  So assignment to token variables is restricted to case of terminal symbols.

Answer (score 3):

```
(o = <I_EXIT> | o = <I_RET> | o = <I_NOP>)
```

is a reasonable solution.

Since your three tokens are completely interchangeable from a syntactic point of view, you could also define one token kind like this.

```
TOKEN:{
    <I_NO_OP: "EXIT" | "RET" | "NOP">
}
```

In this case, you would not define `I_EXIT`, `I_RET`, and `I_NOP`.

Comment: If define a TOKEN `<I_NO_OP: "EXIT" | "RET" | "NOP">`, then the kind will not be `I_EXIT` etc.But right now I don't use kind `I_EXIT ...` anyway.

Comment: Exactly. That you say "right now" suggests to me that you might, in the future, want separate token kinds for the three keywords. If this is the case, the `o = <I_EXIT> | o = <I_RET> | o = <I_NOP>` approach is your best bet.